# How to keep running python script after running openvpn GUI

Tags: python, openvpn

I am struggling in keep running python code after the script starting openvpn run. In my case, I could not run the line `print("hello")` after executing the line `os. system('openvpn --config "path_to_config_openvpn_file"')`. Does anyone can help me to solve this issue, all your help will be appreciated. Thank you

Here is the script:

```
import os, ctypes, sys, time

def is_admin():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False

if is_admin():
    os. system('openvpn --config "path_to_the_openvpn_config_file"')
    # to stop the process but unable to reach theses lines below
    print("hello")
    # os. system('taskkill.exe /F /IM openvpn.exe')
else:
    # Re-run the program with admin rights
    ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use [start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

```
os.system('start "open vpn" /D openvpn.exe --config "path_to_the_openvpn_config_file"')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my self solution for this post. What I did is running stream in daemon mode as the instruction in official website OpenVPN https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/use-openvpn-connect-v3-on-windows-in-service-daemon-mode/?fbclid=IwAR3o4Dv9les4bKhWqkfahG9orBHeQvmyrIV7yMwy1BduduNHKUz3ukZJ7gg